# Show that $\Phi: \mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathcal{P}(B)$ is an injective function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: A \to B$ be a function. We then define a function $\Phi: \mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathcal{P}(B)$ as $\Phi (Z) = f[Z]$. Show that $\Phi$ is and injective function if and only if $f$ is an injective function.

Comment: In what context did you come across this problem? What are your thoughts on it? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Servaes My main problem is that this seems extremely abstract. I know what the basic elements of the problem are, for instance what an injective function is, what a power set is, and have a relatively good grip on them in settings in which I can graph them or otherwise write down the functions (or sets). In contrast, with this kind of problem I often don't even have an idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be injective. Suppose $\Phi$ is not injective. Then there exist, non equal sets $C, D$ such that $\Phi(C) = \Phi(D)$. Since $C \ne D$, there exists an element $c \in C$ not in $D$ or visa versa. Without loss of generality, say $c \in C$. Then, since $f$ is injective, $f(c) \ne f(d)$ for any $d \in D$ so $f(c) \notin f(D) = \Phi(D)$. But $f(c) \in \Phi(C)$, so $\Phi(C) \ne \Phi(D)$, a contradiction. Therefore $\Phi$ is injective.

Now let $\Phi$ be injective and suppose $f$ is not injective. Then there exist $c \ne d$ such that $f(c) = f(d)$. But then

$$\Phi(\{c\}) = \{f(c)\} = \{f(d)\} = \Phi(\{d\})$$

Which contradicts the infectivity of $\Phi$.

Therefore $f$ is injective iff $\Phi$ is injective.